# What did I do wrong in calculating $765_{18} - 210_{3}$?

Tags: binary

So I wanted to calculate

$$765_{18}- 210_{3}$$

First converting $765_{18}$ into decimal: $765_{18} = 2381_{10}$.

Then converting $2381_{10}$ into binary: $2381_{10} = 100101001101_2$

Now converting $210_3$ into decimal: $210_3 = 21_{10}$

Two-complement of $21_{10} = 101011_{2}$

So I now want to add $2381_{10} +(- 21_{10})$ in binary (I just add the binary of $2381_{10}$ with the two-complement of $21_{10}$):

$$ 100101001101_2 + 101011_2 = 100101111000_2$$

I should get $2360_{10}$, but instead, I get $2424_{10}$.

Comment: Check your conversion from $210_3$ to binary. You appear to have one extra 1.

Comment: $210_3 = 21_{10} = 10101_2$?

Comment: Note that $2424_{10} - 2360_{10} = 64_{10} = 100000_{2}$, that should be a hint to the mistake

Comment: @Christoph I guess that means I missed a 1 somewhere?

Comment: The error is in forming that two-complement. $2381_{10}$ is a 12-bit word when in binary. For the subtraction using two-complements to work, both numbers must have the same size. So when two-complementing $21_{10}=10101_2$ you must first extend it to a 12-bit entity $000000010101_2.$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ahh, so that was it!! Thanks :)

Comment: TeachMeJava2017, if you figured this out, you are welcome to post the corrected calculation **as an answer**. That way 1) those of us who are unsure of how subtraction is done using two's complement will have an example, 2) you may get extra feedback on any lingering unclear points, 3) after waiting for a while for such feedback you can then mark the question settled (cleaning up our queue of unanswered questions by a tiny amount :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I edited it and will close it later when its possible. Thanks again :)

Comment: @TeachMeJava2017 The answer should not be part of the question. So instead of editing the question to include the answer you should really post an answer.

Comment: @Christoph Ok, did. (Didn't know this was actually allowed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a hint in the comment I realized that I had to use $12$ bits for $21_{10}$, i.e. $-21_{10} = 111111101011_2$

Now one only has to add both of these:

$$100101001101_2 + 111111101011_2 = 100100111000_2 = 2360_{10}$$

Comment: Glad to see it worked out :-)